# Values of different time periods summed up and matched to certain dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet.

[image]

The spreadsheet is used to plan sales campaigns. The user enters the `start` and `end` date of the sales campaign in **Column B** and **Column C**. In **Column D** the `duration` (number of days) is calculated from those dates. In **Column E** the user enters the `revenue` for the entire campaign. In **Column F:L** the user divides the `revenue` over the days of the `duration`.

In **Column N** each day of the year is listed. 
In **Column O** the sum of the `revenue` based on the values in **Column F:L** should be calculated.

For example **Campaign A** starts at `2018-01-01`, takes `4` days and therefore `300€` go to `2018-01-01`, `100€` go to `2018-01-02` and so on ....

The same applies for all following campaigns. 
Therefore, in **Column O** the sum of the revenue of all campaigns should be calculated so on `2018-01-02` to the `100€` from the second day of **Campaign A** the `120€` from the first day of **Campaign B** should be added. Thus, the total is `220€`.

Do you know a formula that I can use in **Column O** which does exactly the calculation described above?

Comment: you can use countifs().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sumproduct will iterate through testing whether the date is in the range, find where it lands in that range and return the correct value to be summed.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((N2<=$C$2:$C$5)*(N2>=$B$2:$B$5)*("Day " & N2-$B$2:$B$5+1 = $F$1:$L$1),$F$2:$L$5)
```

[image]